# Repetition of constraint in liquidbase and entity definition

Tags: java, jpa

I`ve noticed that in my project some composite constraint are set in a liquidbase,
for example

`constraint importer_ukey unique (name, country_id, is_importer, is_manufacturer)`

but then they are repeated in entity definition in @Table annotation

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(name = "importer_ukey",
                columnNames = {"name", "country_id", "is_importer", "is_manufacturer"})})
```

Is there any positive in repetition of uniqueConstraint in entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than for creating the schema based on the JPA annotations, it is also a needed at runtime for the JPA provider to order INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements correctly.

> Unique constraints ensure that the data in a column or combination of columns is unique for each row. A table's primary key, for example, functions as an implicit unique constraint. In JPA, you represent other unique constraints with an array of UniqueConstraint annotations within the table annotation. The unique constraints you define are used during table creation to generate the proper database constraints, and may also be used at runtime to order INSERT, UPDATE , and DELETE statements. For example, suppose there is a unique constraint on the columns of field F. In the same transaction, you remove an object A and persist a new object B, both with the same F value. The JPA runtime must ensure that the SQL deleting A is sent to the database before the SQL inserting B to avoid a unique constraint violation.

Source: https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_overview_mapping_unq.html

So yes: it is important.